# Oracle SQL Select Split "City, State" to two columns (w/ some instances of just state and no comma) and Trim whitespaces

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

I've seen this solution for data that always has commas but can't seem to get this to work when there are no commas.

Data is coming from a "location" field that looks like this... (where some data is "city, state" and other rows are "state" with no city listed).

```
[location_str]
 Boston, MA
 Miami, FL
 MO
 AK
Fairbanks, AK
```

I'm trying to get them to two columns [City] and [State].

This code almost works...

```
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR (location_str, '[^,]+', 1, 1)    AS City,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR (location_str, '[^,]+', 1, 2)    AS State
FROM    Locations_Table
```

The result is...

```
[City]      [State]
 Boston      MA
 Miami       FL
 MO          NULL
 AK          NULL
 Fairbanks   AK
```

It is close I just need the rows with STATE only and no comma to wind up in the [State] column and for the NULL to wind up in the [City] column.

The last little bit is how to clean up the location_str data which contains trailing and leading spaces in the database (generated somewhere else).

```
[location_str]
" Fairbanks, AK"
"Fairbanks, AK      "
"DC"
"DC      "
"DC   "
```

I can try this tomorrow but can I wrap the REGEXP_SUBSTR in a TRIM func? would the following work on this...

```
TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR (location_str, '[^,]+', 1, 1)) AS City
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need regular expressions for your requirement; standard string functions, like `instr` and `substr`, are faster, and they work perfectly in this situation.

The `WITH` clause is not part of the query; rather, I include it only to generate test data. Remove it, and run the query (starting at `select location_str, ...`) on your actual table.

As you suspected, `TRIM(...)` can be used to trim spaces from both sides of each resulting substring. Please note: this will not handle spaces **within** a name, for example `'San        Francisco'` or `'North   Carolina'`. If needed, these can be handled too, with a bit more work.

```
with
  test_data (location_str) as (
    select 'Boston, MA'          from dual union all
    select '   Miami ,  FL  '    from dual union all
    select 'MO'                  from dual union all
    select '     AK'             from dual union all
    select 'Fairbanks   , AK   ' from dual
  )
select location_str,
       trim(substr(location_str, 1, instr(location_str, ',') - 1)) as city,
       trim(substr(location_str, instr(location_str, ',') + 1))    as state
from   test_data
;

LOCATION_STR        CITY                STATE              
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
Boston, MA          Boston              MA                 
   Miami ,  FL      Miami               FL                 
MO                                      MO                 
     AK                                 AK                 
Fairbanks   , AK    Fairbanks           AK
```

Comment: There are always 5 ways to solve an issue and the other methods work but this one was quick and also included the trim() solution so I'm marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a `case` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN location_str LIKE '%,%'
             THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(location_str, '[^,]+', 1, 1)    
        END) AS City,
       (CASE WHEN location_str LIKE '%,%'
             THEN REGEXP_SUBSTR(location_str, '[^,]+', 1, 2)
             ELSE location_str
        END) AS State
FROM Locations_Table
```

Comment: Nice and simple. I suspect that will be perfect. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: Is there any reason that wrapping the two THEN "REGEXP_SUBSTR" rows and the ELSE location_str in TRIM() functions won't work?

Comment: @TimK . . . It is not obvious to me how `trim()` would be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can add comma to the starting of the value if there is no comma at all and then it will work with your current solution:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR (location_str, '[^,]+', 1, 1)    AS City,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR (location_str, '[^,]+', 1, 2)    AS State
FROM    
(Select case when instr(location_str,',') = 0 then ' ,' end || location_str as location_str
From locations_Table)
```

Cheers!!